# self'/classess on RPi

Tags: python, class, self

Here is couple of my code:
(main class)

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import os
    import pigpio
    import subprocess
    from time import sleep
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    pigpio.exceptions = False
    pi = pigpio.pi()


    class FORWARD(object):
            def __init__(self):
                    self.GPIO = GPIO
                    self.GPIO_TRIGGER = GPIO_TRIGGER
                    self.GPIO_ECHO = GPIO_ECHO


            def setup():
                    ENGA = 4
                    ENGB = 17
                    ENABLEA = 23
                    ENABLEB = 24
                    GPIO.setup(ENGA, GPIO.OUT)
                    GPIO.setup(ENGB, GPIO.OUT)
                    GPIO.setup(ENABLEA, GPIO.OUT)
                    GPIO.setup(ENABLEB, GPIO.OUT)
                    GPIO_TRIGGER = 14
                    GPIO_ECHO = 11


            def frwd(self):
                    GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)
                    GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.OUT)
                    GPIO.output(ENABLEB, True)
                    GPIO.output(ENABLEA, True)
                    GPIO.output(ENGA, False)
                    GPIO.output(ENGB, False)
```

and the sec. file:

```
    from ctrl import FORWARD
    run = FORWARD()
    run.setup()
    run.frwd()
```

And here is my question:
Why it's not working? I am receiving error with the global names:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "go.py", line 2, in <module>
    run = FORWARD()
    File "/root/ctrl.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.GPIO_TRIGGER = GPIO_TRIGGER
    NameError: global name 'GPIO_TRIGGER' is not defined
```

My point is - i just want to make a 'setup' function in which i will define PINS and GPIO outputs, then i want to define more methods (e.g - backward, stop, etc.). So what's about these selfs or how should it write?

Regards,
Maciej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the Python tutorial on classes. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

The first argument to every method on a class is an instance of that class. It's convention to refer to this variable as `self`. So your `setup` method should really have `self` as an argument.

The specific error you are receiving is with the line:

```
self.GPIO_TRIGGER = GPIO_TRIGGER
```

You're attempting to set the `GPIO_TRIGGER` property of the instance to the variable `GPIO_TRIGGER`. However, the `GPIO_TRIGGER` hasn't been defined within the scope that the class is defined. i.e. you haven't defined it anywhere, and haven't imported it from somewhere else. You'll have similar issues with GPIO_ECHO.

Presumably you need to define these variables yourself, e.g.

```
GPIO_TRIGGER = 7
GPIO_ECHO = 8
```

Adjust accordingly to the pins you're using.